# Open a new Safari window in the current Space from Terminal with multiple tabs (URLs)

Tags: terminal, safari, applescript, command-line

How to open an new Safari window from Terminal in the current Space?

Now when using the `open http://example.com` command it opened the URL as last tab on my first Safari window.

I'm looking for a way to open:

- New Safari window (regardless how many I have opened).
- In the current Space
- From Terminal with the provided URL.

It probably will need some `osascript` script, but my AppleScript knowledge is nearly zero...

The bonus could be open two URLs, in two tabs, in a new window in the current Space.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an AppleScript that should help you. Open AppleScript Editor and save this as a script. I have modified the source that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706171/how-to-open-a-new-window-and-multiple-urls-in-safari-with-apple-script) to support taking arguments on the command line.

Use it like this:

`osascript new_window.scpt http://www.google.com http://www.stackoverflow.com`

Of course, replace the URLs above with your own URLs.

---

### new_window.scpt

```
on run argv
    tell application "Safari"
        if (count argv) = 0 then
            -- If you dont want to open a new window for an empty list, replace the
            -- following line with just "return"
            set {first_url, rest_urls} to {"", {}}
        else
            -- `item 1 of ...` gets the first item of a list, `rest of ...` gets
            -- everything after the first item of a list.  We treat the two
            -- differently because the first item must be placed in a new window, but
            -- everything else must be placed in a new tab.
            set {first_url, rest_urls} to {item 1 of argv, the rest of argv}
        end if

        make new document at end of documents with properties {URL:first_url}
        tell window 1
            repeat with the_url in rest_urls
                make new tab at end of tabs with properties {URL:the_url}
            end repeat
        end tell
        activate
    end tell
end run
```

---

You could even create an alias for this in Terminal and be able to use it easier. I would add the following to `~/.bash_profile`:

`alias newwindow='osascript /path/to/new_window.scpt'`

Call `newwindow` whatever you want. Save `.bash_profile` and restart Terminal for it to work.

---

In case anyone is looking for a similar solution for Google Chrome, here is a different take on the same idea.

### chrome_new_window.scpt

```
on run argv
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        if (count argv) = 0 then
            make new window
        else
            tell (make new window)
                set URL of active tab to item 1 of argv
                repeat with the_url in the rest of argv
                    open location the_url
                end repeat
            end tell
        end if
        set active tab index of first window to 1
        activate
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: ABSOLUTELY marvelous. I simple created a script called Safari in my `$PATH` with a shebang `#!/usr/bin/osascript` and works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Didn't know you could do that with `#!/usr/bin/osascript`! Glad to help (and thanks for the new knowledge!)

Comment: thx bro, amazing

Answer (score 4):

What about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444904/terminal-command-to-open-new-safari-window) by user markhunte.

You can place the below function with the osascript code in your `.profile`.

code:

```
function Safari {
  # Will open a New Safari window with argument 1.

osascript <<EOD
tell application "Safari" to make new document with properties {URL:"$1"}
return
EOD

}
```

In terminal:

`cd` to your home directory.

Run:

```
nano .profile
```

If you already have a `.profile` file it will open and there will be some code there already.

Enter the code into it below any other code.

If you did not have one, a blank `.profile` file will be opened.

Enter the code into it.

---

After entering the code:

Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press the <kbd>x</kbd> key.

At the bottom of the window you will be asked to save the changes.

Hit the <kbd>y</kbd> key for yes.

You will now be asked to save it with the current name of `.profile`.

Just hit the enter key to save it.

Run :

```
. ~/.profile
```

This will update the environment.

now you can run:

Safari  "http://stackoverflow.com"
Note the Cap "S" in Safari.

Comment: Thank you too, I more like `vim` for editing. ;) Accepting aglasser's answer because solved the two url problem.